# stringr function to concatenate vector of words separated by comma with "and" before last word

Tags: r, stringr, stringi

I know I can easily write one, but does anyone know if stringr (or stringi) already has a function that concatenates a vector of one or more words separated by commas, but with an "and" before the last word?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `knitr::combine_words` function

```
knitr::combine_words(letters[1:2])
# [1] "a and b"
knitr::combine_words(letters[1:3])
# [1] "a, b, and c"
knitr::combine_words(letters[1:4])
# [1] "a, b, c, and d"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm surprised this function isn't also in stringr

Answer (score 2):

Here's another solution :

```r
enum <- function(x) 
  paste(c(head(x,-2), paste(tail(x,2), collapse = ", and ")), collapse = ", ")
enum(letters[1])
#> [1] "a"
enum(letters[1:2])
#> [1] "a, and b"
enum(letters[1:3])
#> [1] "a, b, and c"
enum(letters[1:4])
#> [1] "a, b, c, and d"
```

<sup>Created on 2019-05-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>